# jquery focus first form element on tab of final

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to get the cursor to jump to focus on the first element of the form.  For some reason it keeps getting focus on the 2nd element instead of the first.  I did just a simple form.

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

$('form').children().keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) {
       if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
         $(this).parent().children().first().focus();
       }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cBGS3/)

See console logs

when you press tab on last element it `focus` the 1st element and then perform `tab` operation so it goes to 2nd element .

---

## Solution

Use [event.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return false` to stop tab operation .

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cBGS3/1/)</kbd> or <kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cBGS3/2/)</kbd>

```
if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
            $(this).parent().children().first().focus();
            e.preventDefault(); // or return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still went to the 2nd form element as well.